# NodeJS Mongoose Query array that is a sub-set of another array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hi there I have a document structure that looks like this.

```
  Users = [
  {
    _id: 32339457349878493,
    books: [
      "Harry Potter",
      "Lord of the Rings",
      "Life of Pi"
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 32339457349878493,
    books: [
      "Life of Pi",
      "The Alchemist",
      "Mocking Jay"
    ]
  },

  {
    _id: 32339457349878493,
    books: [
      "Harry Potter",
      "Life of Pi",
      "The Alchemist",

    ]
  },

  ]
```

I want to make a query ["Harry Potter", "Life of Pi"] which will return me the documents that contains both of these books.

So in this case, the first and third records will be returned!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) which is a shorthand version of `$and`:

```
Users.find({ "books": { "$all":  ["Harry Potter", "Life of Pi"] } },function(err,users) } {

});
```

That basically means that the "books" array must contain both of the arguments specified in order to be a match.

The longer form with `$and` requires the field named twice:

```
{
    "$and": [
        { "books": "Harry Potter" },
        { "books": "Life of Pi" }
    ]
}
```

So it's much nicer to use `$all`.